# Showing uniform convergence of sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}((x-k)^{2}+1))}$ is uniformly convergent for all $ x\in\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt using Weierstrass M-test:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}((x-k)^{2}+1))}|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}((x-k)^{2}+1))}\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-k)^{2}+1}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-k)^{2}}$$

I can expand $(x-k)^{2}=x^{2}-2xk+k^{2}$ not sure how to handle the $x$ though.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right approach for Weierstrass M. Here's what you would like to do: Find constants $M_k$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}M_k <\infty$ and

$$\tag 1\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}\left |\frac{1}{\sqrt k((x-k)^2 + 1)}\right | \le M_k$$

for each $k.$

Again, that's what you'd like to do. Unfortunatley, that's impossible. For each $k$ the supremum in $(1)$ occurs when $x=k,$ giving $1/\sqrt k.$ And $\sum 1/\sqrt k =\infty.$ So Weierstrass M is not going to save the day here.

Hint for another approach: Show there exists $C$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1/((x-k)^2 + 1)\le C$ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$ We then have

$$\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt k((x-k)^2 + 1)} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{((x-k)^2 + 1)} \le \frac{C}{\sqrt N}.$$

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. Doesnt Weierstrass M-test say that if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty M_{k}$ converges then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty f_{k}(x)$ converges too, if and only if $|f_{k}(x)|\le M_{k}$ ?
And in this case $f_{k}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}((x-k)^{2}+1)} $

Comment: No, there's no iff. It's one way.

Comment: Okay yeah its one way my bad. But was my approach for a solution not the M-test or?

Comment: What you wrote is not really a bona fide WMT attempt. We want $|f_k|\le M_k$ on $ \mathbb R$ for all $k$ and $\sum M_k <\infty.$ But what you were after (or at least wrote) was $\sum |f_k(x)| \le \sum M_k < \infty.$ That is not the WMT and it will not prove uniform convergence.

Comment: Okay .. but in your hint, why does the sum start at N?

Comment: It will show the sequence of partial sums is uniformly Cauchy.

Comment: Not sure what uniformly Cauchy is.. we didnt have that theorem in this course..

Comment: It's exactly what you would think, but OK, you don't really need that. Suppose $\sum f_k(x)$ converges pointwise to $f.$ Then $$f(x) - \sum_{k=1}^{N}f_k(x) = \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$$ So if the latter sum can be made uniformly small, you have shown the series converges uniformly.

Comment: Okay but shouldnt we have absolute value on the sum $\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty f_{k}(x) $ ?

Comment: Or rather the supremum..

Comment: So I should show that $$\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}\left |\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt k((x-k)^2 + 1)}\right | \le \epsilon$$ ?